# How to give a size to a vector array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Hello I would like to set 18 elements in my vector array but i'm unsure on how to do it exactly. Would it be like this?

```
vector<byte> Clients(18);
```

or like this?

```
vector<byte> Clients[18];
```

Comment: What is the "vector array"? Is it an array of vectors or you mean only one vector?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'vector array'.  Is it an array of vectors or are you trying to set the size of the vector?

Comment: I wan't to set 1 vector array to hold 18 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are not called vector arrays.  They are usually implemented as arrays in the background, but that doesn't change what they are called.

To answer your question, to change the size of a vector you can use the [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) member function.

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.resize(5);
```

You can also use `resize` to initialize all the values.  For instance, in the following example there are five 0's in the vector.

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.resize(5, 0);
```

Usually, you just push things into a vector and don't have to set a size.  For example:

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myvector.push_back(
}
// you now have a vector with a size of 5 that has initialized 
// values at indices 0 through 4, inclusive.
```

Comment: Ahh I get it now. Thank you :)

1 more thing. How would I implement this into my class and when I call it like for eg. Clients(3).Test(); the 3 in Clients(3). will store it in the vector?

Comment: You can access elements of a vector the same way you would an array, with the `[]` operator.  You can also use the `.at` member function.

Comment: To answer the actual question, `vector<byte> Clients(18)` creates a vector with `18` elements, and `vector<byte> Clients(18, 0)` would create them all initialized to `0` . There's no reason to prefer using the default constructor and then doing `resize` although it is good to know about both methods.

Comment: Thank you for adding that @MattMcNabb, I always forgot about the constructor method of initializing because I pretty much always push/pop things into/from a vector instead of having a set size.